# OPC UA server implementation

Tags: python, opc-ua

Referencing the following video: [An OPC UA sample server in written in python using its opcua module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbKeBfK3pfk&t=22s)

I am trying to implement this server on my own, so that I can later make modifications to it. I have PyDev for Eclipse installed as used in the video.

Here is the code used in the video:

```
from opcua import Server
from random import randint
import datetime
import time

server = Server()

url = "opc.tcp://192.168.0.8:4840"
server.set_endpoint(url)

name = "OPC_SIMULATION_SERVER"
addspace = server.register_namespace(name)

node = server.get_objects_node()

Param = node.add_object(addspace, "Parameters")

Temp = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Temperature", 0)
Press = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Pressure", 0)
Time = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Time", 0)

Temp.set_writable()
Press.set_writable()
Time.set_writable()

server.start()
print("Server started at {}".format(url))

while True:
    Temperature = randint(10,50)
    Pressure = randint(200, 999)
    TIME = datetime.datetime.now()

    print(Temperature, Pressure, TIME)

    Temp.set_value(Temperature)
    Press.set_value(Pressure)

    Time.set_value(TIME)

    time.sleep(2)
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following errors, which appear to be related to one another:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu9Z2.png)

If you could help me identify the source of errors, and possible resolutions to them I would appreciate it.

Edit: I was able to configure the server and it ran as expected. However, I now wish to connect it to a client to read in the data. When I try to do this, the connection is established but no data is read in. What are some potential fixes to this issue?

Comment: Please paste the errors directly, linking them as external image is an absurd.

Comment: Is the URL correct? Tried with 127.0.0.1:4840? Can you start server without nodes?

Comment: @Rekshino, I used the URL you provided and the server ran, but notified me of the same initial "add_node" errors from before. Could you explain your reasoning behind using that URL? Thank you, it was helpful to me.

Comment: IP address for server is actually localhost, for the clients you have to specified real IP, but if you specify real IP for the server, than you can make a typo or IP was changed, or firewall, or something else. Further(I don't know your SDK and quite new for OPC), but can it be, that you miss root node?

Comment: @Rekshino, can you clarify what you mean when you said miss root node? I am new to OPC UA as well. From my understanding, the line  `node = server.get_objects_node()` should create the root node?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not aware about python and OPC-UA modul.